# How do i get last sunday date from a given date in unix

Tags: bash, shell, datetime, unix, unix-timestamp

get last sunday date as output from a given date (not current date) as input

Example input: 08-30-2017 (%m-%d-%Y)

output should be last sunday: 08-27-2017

===

All of the below commands use current day as reference .But i want to give the reference date as input to get last sunday. Please help me with the command.

date +%m-%d-%Y -d "2017-09-10 -7 days"

date +%m-%d-%Y -d "last Sun"

Comment: will the input date always be in such format `%m-%d-%Y` on your side?

Answer (score 3):

I hope this below solution can help you:

```
export day=08-30-2017
date -d "$day -$(date -d $day +%w) days"
```

This will always print the Sunday before the given date (or the date itself).

```
date -d "$day -$(date -d $day +%u) days"
```

This will always print the Sunday before the given date (and never the date itself).

Comment: To get last monday from a given date? what should be changed? Like i want last Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed.. till the date given as input.Please help me with this

Comment: @DivyaS to get Monday: `date -d "$day -$(date -d $day +%u) days + 1 day"` and keep on adding days for Tue and Wed. Try this.

Comment: Last edit reverted. Why did you copy/paste @RomanPerekhrest 's answer?

Comment: @Toto I didn't copy anyone's answer dude! Check the time I posted/edited my answer and then another person's answer. Revert it back to my edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with a fixed date format `%m-%d-%Y`, it should be transformed to `%Y-%m-%d` format to be processed by `date` function:

```
d='08-30-2017'
d=${d##*-}-${d%-*}
lst_sunday=$(date -d "$d -$(date -d $d +%u) days" +"%m-%d-%Y")

echo $lst_sunday
08-27-2017
```

---

`+%u` - interpreted format specificator, day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday

Comment: To get last monday from a given date? what should be changed?    Like i want last Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed.. till the date given as input.Please help me with this.

Comment: @DivyaS, try to work with variable `d` as in my approach and you'll see

Comment: yes i did a copy paste.. Its working fine.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple way-

First calculate dayofweek from given date. It will be 1-7. For Monday it's 1 etc ...Saturday 6 and Sunday 7.

Then subtract dayofweek from given date. That's your last Sunday.

```
$ givenDate="08-30-2017"
$ dayofweek=$(date -j -f '%m-%d-%Y' $givenDate +'%u')
$ date -j -f '%m-%d-%Y' -v-${dayofweek}d $givenDate +%m-%d-%Y
08-27-2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is function to query someday (1..7) from somedate (MM-DD-YYYY),

```
function query_last_date(){
  declare -A week_day
  week_day[1]="mon"
  week_day[2]="tue"
  week_day[3]="wed"
  week_day[4]="thu"
  week_day[5]="fri"
  week_day[6]="sat"
  week_day[7]="sun"
  t="$1"
  query_last_day=$2
  d=${t##*-}-${t%-*}
  inp_day=$(date -d $d +%u)

  if test $query_last_day -gt $inp_day; then
    offset=$(expr $inp_day + 7 - $query_last_day)
  else
    offset=$(expr $inp_day - $query_last_day)
  fi

  out_date=$(date -d "$d -$offset days" +"%m-%d-%Y")
  echo "inp_date $t (${week_day[$inp_day]}) -> out_date $out_date (${week_day[$query_last_day]})"
}

query_last_date 09-30-2021 1
query_last_date 09-30-2021 2
query_last_date 09-30-2021 3
query_last_date 09-30-2021 4
query_last_date 09-30-2021 5
query_last_date 09-30-2021 6
query_last_date 09-30-2021 7
```

Expected output is as follows,

```
inp_date 09-30-2021 (thu) -> out_date 09-27-2021 (mon)
inp_date 09-30-2021 (thu) -> out_date 09-28-2021 (tue)
inp_date 09-30-2021 (thu) -> out_date 09-29-2021 (wed)
inp_date 09-30-2021 (thu) -> out_date 09-30-2021 (thu)
inp_date 09-30-2021 (thu) -> out_date 09-24-2021 (fri)
inp_date 09-30-2021 (thu) -> out_date 09-25-2021 (sat)
inp_date 09-30-2021 (thu) -> out_date 09-26-2021 (sun)
```